# Проверка Инпута на пустоту JavaScript

Tags: javascript, input

```
 var button = document.querySelectorAll('.send')    
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var inputName = document.querySelector('#error').value;
        if(inputName == ''){
            alert('z');
        }
    })
```

Скажите как проверить инпут на пустоту, этот код не работает D:::: Я уже не знаю что делать

Comment: "не знаете что делать"? А загуглить пытались?

Comment: Пытался, прочесал пару десятков сайтов но тщетно

Answer (score 3):

`document.querySelectorAll('.send')` ключивой момент `All`, значит нужен цикл.
Или же индекс `button[индекс].addEventListener('click', function() {`

```js
var button = document.querySelectorAll('.send');
var input = document.querySelector('#error');
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (input.value !== '') {
      console.log('НЕ пустой');
    }else{
    console.log('Пустой');
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<input id="error" />
<button class="send">button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно проверять так  `if (inputName.length === 0){...}`

Comment: @Air: я вижу честную попытку ответа на вопрос. Стоит помнить, что плохой или даже неверный ответ является ответом (можно минус ставить, но не следует писать "не является ответом") [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/137096)

Comment: @jfs, Странно, а к чему тогда проверки? Почему бы его не удалить, если не несет никакой пользы...   Ну тогда и yt надо его отмечать тревогой...  Любой ответ это ответ... И не будем проверять ни какой

Comment: @Air вы на ссылочку нажмите, там подробно объяснено что является ответом, а что нет. Если читать сложно, просто  на картинку посмотрите.¶ Примеры "не ответов": новый вопрос, который как ответ опубликован; вопрос к автору, опубликованный как ответ; полезная ссылка; спам.

Comment: @jfs Я не владею английским....